# Separate functions into validation and implementation? Why?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I was reading a C# book in which the author (some dude named Jon Skeet) implements a `Where` function like

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T> ( this IEnumerable<T> source, Funct<T,bool> predicate ) 
{
    if ( source == null || predicate == null ) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    return WhereImpl(source, predicate);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> WhereImpl<T> ( IEnumerable <T> source, Func<T,bool> predicate ) 
{
    foreach ( T item in source ) 
    {
      if ( predicate(item) )  
      {
         yield return item;
      }
    }

}
```

Now, I fully understand how this works and that it's equivalent to

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T> ( this IEnumerable<T> source, Funct<T,bool> predicate ) 
{
    if ( source == null || predicate == null ) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    foreach ( T item in source ) 
    {
      if ( predicate(item) )  
      {
         yield return item;
      }
    }
}
```

which brings up the question of why would one separate these into 2 functions given that there would be memory/time overhead and of course more code. I always validate parameters and if I start writing like this example then I'll be writing twice as much code. Is there some school of thought which holds that validation and implementation should be separate functions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is that the iterator block is always lazy. Unless you call `GetEnumerator()` and then `MoveNext()`, the code in the method won't get executed.

In other words, consider this call to your "equivalent" method:

```
var ignored = OtherEnumerable.Where<string>(null, null);
```

No exception is thrown, because you're not calling `GetEnumerator()` and then `MoveNext()`. Compare that with my version where the exception is thrown *immediately* regardless of how the return value is used... because it only calls the method with the iterator block *after* validating eagerly.

Note that async/await has similar issues - if you have:

```
public async Task FooAsync(string x)
{
    if (x == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));
    }
    // Do some stuff including awaiting
}
```

If you call this, you'll end up getting a faulted `Task` - rather than a `NullReferenceException` being thrown. If you await the returned `Task`, *then* the exception will be thrown, but that may not be where you called the method. That's okay in most cases, but worth knowing about.

Comment: BTW using *code contracts* maybe wouldn't be a real reason to separate them in two methods, because parameter validation would be done using pre-conditions... I can't test this now, but I'm not sure if *code contracts* would be also evaluated as part of the iterator block

Comment: Well, finally I've tested it myself, I was curious about the scenario I said you in the above comment. I've posted my own answer to contribute with this exception to the rule

Answer (score 5):

It may depend of the scenario and your coding style. Jon Skeet is absolutely right about why they should be separated when you're using `yield` to create iterators.

BTW, I thought it could be interesting adding my two cents here: same code using *Code Contracts* (i.e. *design by contract*) behaves in a different way.

Pre-conditions aren't part of the iterator block, thus, the following code will throw a contract exception immediately if the whole pre-conditions aren't met:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        Contract.Requires(source != null);
        Contract.Requires(predicate != null);

        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}

// This throws a contract exception directly, no need of 
// enumerating the returned enumerable
Test.Where<string>(null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

A method using `yield return` looks very nice and simple, but if you examine the compiled code you will notice it gets quite complicated.

The compiler generates a new class for you with state machine logic to support the enumeration. For the 2nd `Where` method, it's around 160 lines of code after decompilation. The actual `Where` method is compiled to

```
[IteratorStateMachine(typeof(IterarorTest.<Where>d__0<>))]
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    IterarorTest.<Where>d__0<T> expr_07 = new IterarorTest.<Where>d__0<T>(-2);
    expr_07.<>3__source = source;
    expr_07.<>3__predicate = predicate;
    return expr_07;
}
```

As you can see, no arguments are checked in this method. It just returns a new iterator.

The arguments are checked in the auto-generated class' `MoveNext` method (the code is a bit too long to post here).

On the other hand, if you move the `yield return` to another method, the arguments are checked immediately when you call the `Where` method - which is the expected behavior here.

**Edit**

As [noticed by Matias Fidemraizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187364/4588915), code contracts also solve the problem - the contract checks are inserted in the `Where` method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    __ContractsRuntime.Requires(source != null, null, "source != null");
    __ContractsRuntime.Requires(predicate != null, null, "predicate != null");
    IterarorTest.<Where>d__0<T> expr_27 = new IterarorTest.<Where>d__0<T>(-2);
    expr_27.<>3__source = source;
    expr_27.<>3__predicate = predicate;
    return expr_27;
}
```